# How to get category URL with the slug?

Tags: categories, permalinks, taxonomy, id, link-category

I have a variable that contains the slug of a category. With that slug I want to create a link to the archive page that displays all the posts in that specific category. What is the best or fastest way to go from slug to category URL?

Preferably I don't want to use a lot of variables (like when going from slug > id > url, each with a different variable). I would like a function that does one of the following, to keep the file as clean as possible.

`echo get_url_function(slug)` or `echo get_url_function( get_id_function (slug) )`

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WP function [`get_category_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category_link/) will do the trick.

```
/**
 * Gets the URL for a category term archive based on the category's slug.
 *
 * @param string $category_slug The slug of the category to get the category arcive for.
 *
 * @return string The category (term) archive URL. Empty string on error.
 */
function wpse_get_category_url_by_slug( $category_slug ) {
    return get_category_link( get_cat_ID( $category_slug ) );
}
```

Instead of a creating a wrapper like the example above, you could also just call the WP function directly: `get_category_link( get_cat_ID( $category_slug ) )`

Comment: Hi @DaveRomsey thanks for your answer. It worked great!